# Testing with spring boot oauth2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

So I have migrated an app to use azure ad for authentication. Previously, method security was tested using `@WithMockUser`. Eg:

```
@Test
@WithMockUser
someTestMethod() {
  // some test code
}
```

However, when I try to run the application now, I get the following error:

```
Field repo in com.azure.spring.cloud.autoconfigure.aad.AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' that could not be found.
```

The security config extends AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter like:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
}
```

I think the problem is that the Security config extends from AadWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. I have tried overriding that in tests like:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(1)
public class TestSecurityConfig {
}
```

Without luck.

I would like to be able to run tests without using the oauth client.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Can you add also `yml` file for testing and application ?

Comment: @AndreiLisa There really isnt anything related to the security, but I have updated the question with more code.

Comment: yep. i think the answer that @ch4mp gave helped you.

Comment: Extending a `SecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated (even in Spring Security 5 / Boot 2). When migrating to latest Spring Boot version, see [this starter I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#oidc-starter) for an easy way to build your `SecurityFilterChain` beans for OAuth2 (working with any OpenID Provider).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@WithMockUser` sets the test security context with a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` which is not adapted to OAuth2: `Authentication` implementation should probably be one of:

- `JwtAuthenticationToken` (resource server with JWT decoder)
- `BearerTokenAuthentication` (resource server with token introspection, aka "opaque token")
- `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` (client with `oauth2Login`)

If you want to use annotations, see [this libs I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#unit-tests). It provides with the annotations you need and the repo contains plenty of working samples, all unit and integration tested.

I also contributed to `spring-security-test` some `MockMvc` request post-processors and `WebTestClient` mutators for OAuth2. But of course, those require the usage of either `MockMvc` or `WebTestClient`, and, as so, are limited to testing `@Controller`. In contrast, annotations can be used to test any secured `@Component` (like `@Repository` or `@Service` with `@PreAuthorize` and alike). Also, in my opinion, annotations make tests much more readable.

For more details, you may refer to the [README chapter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master#unit-tests) I already linked or this [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-oauth-testing-access-control) (but it is a bit outdated: annotations have improved since I wrote it).